# In ASP.NET Core Web API - Not able to upload a file into database but file is getting saved in the path

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API, and I'm trying to upload a file into the mentioned path `Upload\\Files`, and also store the file path into the database.

While testing with Swagger, file is getting uploaded into the folder successfully but the file path is not getting saved into the database.

This is the `Program.cs` file:

```
using FileUploadContenet.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Globalization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(Options =>
{
    Options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLServerConnection"));
});

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Here is the `appsettings.json`:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLServerConnection": "Server=ServerName;Database=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True; Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Here is the data table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UploadContent] 
(
    [Id]         INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [fileUpload] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_UploadContent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

This is the model class:

```
public class UploadContent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string fileUpload { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the `ApplicationDbContext` file:

```
using FileUploadContenet.Model;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FileUploadContenet.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<UploadContent> UploadContent { get; set; }
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IConfiguration configuration) : base(options)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLServerConnection"));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my API controller code:

```
using FileUploadContenet.Data;
using FileUploadContenet.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using System.Globalization;

namespace FileUploadContenet.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FilesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public FilesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("UploadFile")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var result = await WriteFile(file);
            return Ok(result);
        }

        private async Task<string> WriteFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            string filename = "";

            try
            {
                //var extension = "." + file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
                //filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + extension;
                var extension = "." + file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
                filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + extension;

                var directoryPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Upload\\Files");

                if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
                }

                var filePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, filename);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }

                // Save the file path to the database
                SaveFilePathToDatabase(filePath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions (log or return an error)
            }

            return filename;
        }

        private void SaveFilePathToDatabase(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                var uploadContent = new UploadContent
                {
                    fileUpload = filePath
                };

                _context.UploadContent.Add(uploadContent);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not stored into the database");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: I'm not getting any error message

Comment: Set a breakpoint at "// Handle exceptions (log or return an error)" and "Console.WriteLine("File not Stored into the Datbase");" or add some real error logging there to see whether there is an exception

Comment: No there is not exceptions, I did try the Breakpoint with Error Message.

Comment: Consider using [FILESTREAM or FileTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/binary-large-object-blob-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16). Also use `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov this post is about saving the "file path" into DB.

Comment: Exactly! @derloopkat  I want to save the File Path into DB, I am already able to upload the file into the mentioned Path. and I did try using await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
Still getting the same issue.

Comment: Could you please check what are you getting here `SaveFilePathToDatabase(string filePath)`? and are you geting the ID saved? fileUpload is null or empty in database?

Comment: @derloopkat I am getting no error or any message , I did try breakpoint on SaveFilePathToDatabase(string filePath)
And Id is not getting saved, it's NULL in the database

Comment: I have tried the way I provided, I think your DbContext class need to be updated. I have tried the given way and eveything seems working accordingly. In addition, `builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");` this line also not required for the Uplaod db operation if you don't have other operation related to that. If you have any other concern feel free to let me know.